# How to avoid Scan pair: <nil> *json.RawMessage errors on nullable JSON columns?

Tags: sql, json, go

Several weeks ago I started to learn go and trying to build a simple blogging application while learning the basics.

Currently I'm trying to fetch and persist blog posts using `database/sql` and `github.com/lib/pq` packages. I dont prefer utilizing 3rd party packages like `sqlx` or `gorm` without fully understand the native behaviours and basics of the go.

My `Post` struct is something like this:

```
type Post struct {
    Id        int
    Title     string
    Body      string
    Tags      json.RawMessage
}
```

When persisting posts, my `save()` function works without any problem:

```
func (p *Post) save() (int, error) {
    const query = `INSERT INTO post (title, body, tags) VALUES($1, $2, $3) RETURNING id`
    db := GetDB()
    var postid int
    err := db.QueryRow(query, p.Title, p.Body, p.Tags).Scan(&postid)
    return postid, err
}
```

and to read the latest posts, I wrote a small function:

```
func getLatestPosts(page int) (*[]Post, error) {
    const query = `SELECT id, title, body, tags FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10`
    var items []Post
    db := GetDB()
    rows, err := db.Query(query)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    for rows.Next() {
        var item Post
        if err := rows.Scan(&item.Id, &item.Title, &item.Body, &item.Tags); err != nil {        
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        items = append(items, item)
    }
    return &items, err
}
```

This also works until hitting a post row which tags column is null and I'm getting the following error at this point:

> 2015/04/16 21:53:04 sql: Scan error on column index 4: unsupported
>   driver -> Scan pair:  -> *json.RawMessage

My question is, what is the proper way to handle `nullable json` columns while scanning the resultset? Is this error related with the `lib/pq`?

My schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE post (
    "id" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('post_id_seq'::regclass),
    "title" varchar(255) NOT NULL COLLATE "default",
    "body" text COLLATE "default",
    "tags" json,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id") NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE
);
```

and here is an already persisted (not-null) `tags` field content:

```
 {
     "black-and-white" : "Black and White",
     "the-godfather" : "The Godfather"
 }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using `json.RawMessage`? Why not just `[]byte`?

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: change your struct to have `Tags *json.RawMessage` or use a temporary of that type.

Note you can [search the Go source](https://golang.org/search?q=unsupported+driver+-%3E+Scan+pair) for the error message to get a better idea of what's going on behind the scenes if you're interested (the standard packages are mostly a good source of well written Go code).

I tested against a fresh PostgreSQL-9.4.1 server with the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE post (
        "id"    serial          PRIMARY KEY,
        "title" varchar(255)    NOT NULL,
        "body"  text,
        "tags"  json
);
```

(by the way, it's probably better to give the commands to re-create, or that where used to create the table rather than the form use gave which can't directly be used. Also, when I was familiar with PostgreSQL I recall it was exceedingly rare that a `varchar` column wasn't a mistake instead of just using `text`, possibly with a length constraint.)

Using that table with your struct type I got:

```
converting Exec argument #2's type: unsupported type json.RawMessage, a slice
```

On the insert. Changing to `[]byte(p.Tags)` made that go away (but see below) and then querying worked as you had it.

I only got the same error you did on querying when I put a NULL value into the table. The solution to this was to change the struct field to `Tags *json.RawMessage`. I could then remove the cast I added on insert and and the query worked fine, either setting the field to `nil` or not as appropriate.

If you do this, don't forget to check if `item.Tags` is `nil` before using it. Alternatively, make the database field `NOT NULL`.

I'm not overly familiar with Go's database support to know if requiring a pointer to a slice to handle NULLs is reasonable; I'd have hoped not since Go already distinguishes between an empty slice and a nil slice.

Alternatively, you can leave your type as-is and use a temporary like this:

```
    var item post
    var tmp *json.RawMessage
    if err := rows.Scan(&item.Id, &item.Title, &item.Body, &tmp); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if tmp != nil {
        item.Tags = *tmp
    }
```

You'll likely experience a similar issue when you test with a NULL body. Either make the database column `NOT NULL` or use `sql.NullString`, either in your type or as a temporary as above (using the `Valid` field of `NullString` to see if you should copy the string).

---

A few other minor notes:

- `golint` suggests using `ID` instead of `Id`.
- You don't provide your `GetDB` implementation, I hope it's just getting a shared/global `*sql.DB`. You don't want to call `sql.Open` repeatedly.
- In both of your functions you could use a [pre-prepared](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Prepare) statement (created once outside those functions). That might help if you call those functions often.
- Your query tries to use the "posts" table/view instead of "post"; I'm guessing a typo while cut-n-pasting to the question?
- Your `getLatestPosts` function reutrns `*[]Post`; don't do that. Just return `[]Post`. You almost never want to use a pointer to a slice, and certainly not as a return type.

Comment: Interesting, I only have an old PostgreSQL server running that lacks the "json" type you appear to be using so I substituted "text" … but that works going directly into a `json.RawMessage` field so I suspect the above won't help and the problem may be related to the pq driver and "json" fields.

Comment: Okay, with an updated postgresql with a json query works fine they way you had it but on insert I had to use `[]byte(item.Tag)`

Comment: Answer changed due to the above testing (the revision history has my old not-so-correct answer for anyone interested)